# Ubuntu 14.04 not booting

Tags: boot

I downloaded ubuntu 14.04 and burn it to disk and when i boot my desktop pc with ubuntu live dvd then only ubuntu startup logo appeared with purple background and nothing happened after it.But i also creat a live usb with unetbootin and here also same problem exists.

Comment: Refer:http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076

Answer (score 0):

Download the LTS here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/

Or if you're a GNOME fan like myself download that image here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME

Download YUMI and use  rather than unetbootin.

create your boot device using YUMI and selecting the downloaded ISO.

Boot again then and try

Comment: i used yumi but nothing happened new and the problem exist same